# Goldbach’s conjecture

Tags: number-theory

I read about this conjecture on the internet and I found that is not proven yet. So I began to think why  is impossible and one day I’ve had an idea. I am going to show it to you and I wait your response on it. I would be very happy if you have any suggestions or remarks.

The conjecture states that “Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes”. Of course that there are variations of the statement but I believe that this is the essence.

Now, let x be an even number greater than 2 and p,q two prime numbers.Because x is even, x can be the sum of two even numbers or two odd numbers.
Assume that x is the sum of two even numbers(that p,q).Because p,q are primes, it means that the only prime even number is 2.And from that p has to be equal to q and equal to 2.So we have that x=2+2=4 which fits the conjecture.

But what happens if x is the sum of two odd numbers? Again, because p,q are primes, it results that p,q are odd primes bigger than 2 (we already knew that because every prime number greater than 2 is odd).
And now begins the "idea."

Suppose that p is not prime, p greater than 2.From the theorem above, p is not odd which means it is even.

But if p is not prime, p is the product of primes so:
p=a1 x a2 x… x an where  a1, a2,…,an are primes bigger than 2.

Because p is a product of prime numbers bigger than 2, we conclude that a1,…,an are odd. So in the end p is the product of odd numbers so it’s odd.

Finally, we assumed that p is not prime which meant that p is even and  showed that p is odd(contradiction). So the assumption is false…and from that p is prime.
It goes the same with q.

Is this ok? Am I missing something or my logic is not good?

I want to say that this  is just a little attempt, just an idea…is the reason why I need your help, advice or piece of information.Any comment is welcomed. Sorry if my English is bad.

Thank you!

Comment: You are right -- in saying that "my logic is not good".

Comment: This is a very well known conjecture in number theory, which has been under the consideration of the greatest mathematicians during hundred of years: it is a rather strange idea to think that one can solve it in five sentences of text. If you enjoy number theory, I suggst you pick a textbook on the subect of which there are many good ones, and study it,

Comment: SteamyRoot- you are right.I haven't noticed that.Thanks for your comment!

Comment: "Suppose that p is not prime,p greater than 2.From the theorem above,p is not odd which means it is even." You somehow deduce that $p$ not being prime implies $p$ being even?

Also, you don't "prove" that every even integer can be written as the sum of two primes - you seem to "prove" that *every* way of writing an even integer as the sum of two other integers $p+q$, implies these $p$ and $q$ to be prime.

Comment: Mariano Suavez-Alvarez-Thanks for the response.Number theory is something new for me so I expect a lot of corrections on this post.

Comment: I think the main problem in your proof is that you supposed the result true ! In fact, you take two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ and you suppose that $x$ (the even number you want to show that is the sum of two even numbers) is the sum of $p$ and $q$...

Comment: Ged- I agree with you.Now I really start to understand the difficulty of this.Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$24=9+15$ gives an example of an even number which is the sum of two odd numbers, neither of which is prime.  So this is a multiple counter-example to your logic (there are many more), which said

> Suppose that $p$ is not prime, $p$ greater than $2$. From the theorem above, $p$ is not odd which means it is even

In fact any odd non-prime would be a counter-example and $9$ is the smallest composite odd number

The fact that $24=5+19=7+17=11+13$ shows $24$ is not a counterexample to the Goldbach conjecture

Comment: Henry- Thank you very much for your comment.I know that there are big gaps in my thinking.But this helps me understand better the conjecture and also where I'm wrong